# Movie about a Teenage Girl that could see another dimension

Tags: identify-this-movie

Some years ago (2 to 4, don't actually remember) I went to the cinema and watched a movie trailer that took my attention and I can't remember its name.

As much as I can tell, there was a girl (10/16 years) who had an object (maybe a ring) that when she touched it, she could see another dimension. I remember a scene where she was travelling by car and she touched it and suddenly she was in a huge green field. The other thing I remember but am not entirely sure is that this world looked a little bit more futuristic.

Comment: Tomorrowland, starring George Clooney?

Answer (score 9):

You are describing Tomorrowland. The titular Tomorrowland is the futuristic (Now [Zeerust](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Zeerust) future-retro) city of Tomorrow, with jet packs and 1960's styling. The teenage girl is Casey Newton, played by Britt Robertson. The scene you describe happens fairly early in the movie:

[From Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrowland_(film)):

> Tomorrowland (subtitled A World Beyond in some regions) is a 2015 American science-fiction mystery adventure film directed and co-written by Brad Bird. ... The film stars George Clooney, Hugh Laurie, Britt Robertson, Raffey Cassidy, Tim McGraw, Kathryn Hahn, and Keegan-Michael Key. In the film, a disillusioned genius inventor (Clooney) and a teenage science enthusiast (Robertson), embark to an ambiguous dimension known as "Tomorrowland", where their actions directly affect the world and themselves.